# how to pass basic auth into selenium with nightwatchjs not in the url

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am writing some tests with [nightwatchjs](http://nightwatchjs.org/) and require a uname and pword for basic authentication.

I am aware of the ability to pass these creds via the url.

However on the site I am working on, passing the credentials in via the URL breaks some of the sites javascript.

Does anyone know another way of passing the creds into the usual popup box?

Comment: What if you would pass the credentials via URL which would log you in and then "get" the page again but without the credentials?..just a thought.

Comment: hmm.. yes good idea that might work but this would need to be done on every test which could get a little tedious :/ I wonder if there's another way

Comment: Well, if this is gonna work, you may extract it to a separate "setup" function and reuse..just to follow the DRY principle..what I know for sure is that you cannot control the http login popup via selenium..

Comment: there is a way to set a globally applied setup function? ooo... how do you do that?

Comment: I mean just apply the Extract method refactoring method, define the function in a helper library and require it in your tests to avoid repeating the same code in every test..it's just a general idea. Hope it helps.

Comment: ahh i see, indeed. I checked your idea and it worked as expected. I wonder if there is a way of auto running a setup function on every test rather than including the the function in each and every test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to make 2 `get()` requests - the first one with the credentials in the URL to log in and the second one without - at this point you'll be logged in.

In `nightwatch.js` there is this `setUp()` test initialization function which you can define in a separate utils/helpers file and require in each test:

```
var utils = require("./utils.js");

module.exports = {
    setUp: utils.setUp,

    // rest of the test
}
```

where `utils.setUp` function would at least contain the "get" request with credentials inside. The downside of this approach is having these `require()` calls in every test file you have. I'm not too familiar with nightwatch.js, there could be a better way to have a global setup/teardown, see:

- [Support for global setUp and tearDown methods](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/212)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Would be ace if the said setUp function could autorun without having to be called into each test.

Comment: @John from what I understand, the global setup/teardown functions are not built-in..thanks.